# How to upload a JSON to google cloud storage using python

Tags: python, json, upload, blob, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to load this code to upload a json to my google cloud via python.

```
import boto
import gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin
import os
import shutil
import StringIO
import tempfile
import time

from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.storage import blob

client = storage.Client(project='dataworks-356fa')
bucket = client.get_bucket('dataworks-356fa-backups')
blob = ('t.json', bucket)
with open('t.json', 'rb'):
  blob.upload_from_file('t.json')
```

I am following the guideline on [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-blobs.html)...

I am stuck and do not know where to go so any help will be greatly appreciated. I have changed the `blob.upload_from_file('t.json')` with `blob.upload('t.json')` and get the same problem.

Comment: Post your error code here please.

Comment: `upload_from_file` method takes `file object` as argument, and you are passing filename to `upload_from_file` method.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uploadcloud.py", line 16, in <module>
    blob.upload_from_file('t.json')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'upload_from_file'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use an instance of the class Blob but are using a tuple by mistake. Try this:

```
client = storage.Client(project='dataworks-356fa')
bucket = client.get_bucket('dataworks-356fa-backups')
blob = bucket.blob('t.json')
with open('t.json', 'rb') as json_file:
  blob.upload_from_file(json_file)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uploadcloud.py", line 16, in <module>
    blob.upload_from_file('f')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 891, in upload_from_file client, file_obj, content_type, size, num_retries)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 815, in _do_upload
client, stream, content_type, size, num_retries)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 634, in _do_multipart_upload
    data = stream.read()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: I'm guessing you're still calling upload_from_file('t.json'). It should be upload_from_file(f).